# Using Bing maps on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am using bing map sample application http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Simple-Map-control-sample-fc94908f
When I execute this code I get nothing on my phone screen but just a blank screen
I have turned on location in my device,and also ID_CAP_MAP and ID_CAP_LOCATION in capabilities.However bing sample projects developed for windows phone 7 are working fine on my device after giving my credentials.Can anybody tell me whats wrong with windows phone 8 bing maps?
The device i am using is Lumia 620

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite simple:

- For Bing Maps add reference to `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps`. This DLL should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries`
- Than change

> xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"

to

> xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"

And that's all now you are using Bing Maps

Answer (score 0):

Read this manual [Maps and navigation for Windows Phone 8 MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)